# How to get HTML elements from dynamically generated page in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to sign in my account  in 
[Figure eight](https://contributors.figure-eight.work/login)

using selenium and python but i can't because there is no any HTML elements in the page only these lines exist.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="ie=edge" http-equiv="x-ua-compatible">
    <title>Figure Eight Contributor Portal</title>
    <link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" />
    <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
    </div>
    <script src="/1.index.js?eca43d17e540e40a3231" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/index.js?eca43d17e540e40a3231" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Surprisingly when i use inspect element i can get the HTML elements.
Searching for similar topic on stackoverflow and google but can't find any solution.
My code trying to sign in is :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import presence_of_element_located
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome

def sign_in(driver, url):
    driver.get(url)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(presence_of_element_located(driver.find_element_by_id('Email')))
    username = driver.find_element_by_id("Email")
    password = driver.find_element_by_id("Password")
    username.send_keys("##########")
    password.send_keys("@@@@@@@@@@")
    driver.find_element_by_name("Sign in").click()
    return True, "Success"

url = "https://contributors.figure-eight.work/login"
driver = Chrome()
result, message = sign_in(driver, url)
if result:
    print(message)
```

Comment: Please remember to mark the answer that solves your issue. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Your locators are not correct. There are no elements on the page with IDs of "Email" or "Password". You also should be waiting for visibility of and not presence of. Presence of means the element exists in the DOM but may or may not be interacted with. Waiting for visibility will ensure that it's present and ready to be interacted with.

Comment: @JeffC This statement _...Waiting for visibility will ensure that it's present and ready to be interacted with..._ is completely **wrong**, **incorrect** and **misleading**. _Visibility_ ensures _the expectation for checking that the element is present on the DOM of a page and visible. Visibility means that the elements are not only displayed but also has a height and width that is greater than 0_ but doesn't guarantees **clickability** / **interactability**. For **clickability** / **interactability** you need `element_to_be_clickable()`

Comment: @DebanjanB 1. If you look at OP's code, the only thing he's using a wait on is the email address element. That doesn't need to be clicked, it only needs to be interacted with using sendkeys so waiting for visible is enough. 2.If you look at [the source](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.html#element_to_be_clickable) for wait for clickable, you will see that it waits for visible and not disabled. Not disabled only applies to INPUT elements so that check will be true on all other elements all the time anyway so is unnecessary.

Comment: @DebanjanB Also... wrong and incorrect mean the same thing and misleading is less severe than wrong. Before telling others they are wrong, you should probably make sure you are right.

Comment: @JeffC I think rather then criticizing OP's attempts you need to help them out. But now you are disappointing us with _...doesn't need to be clicked, it only needs to be interacted..._, do you still find them different?

Comment: @DebanjanB I'm lost at what you are trying to accomplish here. I didn't criticize anything. You should read my comment again. Yes, clicked and interacted many times are different. If you send keys to an element, are you interacting with that element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To send a *character sequence* to the **Email** and **Password** field you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://contributors.figure-eight.work/login')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='email']"))).send_keys("mohammed@awni.com")
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='password']").send_keys("mohammed@awni.com")
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.b-Login__ButtonHolder>a").click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://contributors.figure-eight.work/login')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='email']"))).send_keys("mohammed@awni.com")
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='password']").send_keys("mohammed@awni.com")
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='b-Login__ButtonHolder']/a").click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports:

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: future-eight]

Answer (score 1):

All the elements are present on the page and you can find those by inspecting any element on the page on chrome or firefox.

You can sign in using the code(Have added the xpaths for all the elements in the code below):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import 
presence_of_element_located
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome



def sign_in(driver, url):
    driver.get(url)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
    presence_of_element_located(
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='email']")))
    username = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='email']")
    password = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='password']")
    username.send_keys("##########")
    password.send_keys("@@@@@@@@@@")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='Sign in']").click()
    return True, "Success"

url = "https://contributors.figure-eight.work/login"
driver = Chrome()
result, message = sign_in(driver, url)
if result:
    print(message)
```

Comment: There is an error in your code TypeError: find_element() argument after * must be a sequence, not WebElement.
I had to replace WebDriverWait(driver,60).until(presence_of_element_located(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='email']")))
with     
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='email']"))).send_keys("######")
to work.

Comment: @mohammedawni thanks for letting me know that, i might have missed that because i used your code and just replaced the xpaths in that.